# Audio is overlapping when incoming call answered by specific audio

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm trying to play audio file when incoming call is received by code.The problem is that when the incoming call is received , the audio file start playing two times or overlapping the voice. Also the issue is After ending call the audio file doesn't pause or stop it will keep playing until audio file not ends.
The code  i have tried for this is as below:

```
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

     try{
        final MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.audio);

        String state= intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AcceptCall.class);
                    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                    context.startActivity(intent1);

                        mp.setLooping(false);
                        mp.start();


                    }


            }, 4000);

        }
        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){

            try{
                mp.reset();
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);

                Toast.makeText(context, "Idle!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Help me out from this

Comment: What do your logs say about the problem?

Comment: there is nothing in log ,the application launched successfully but the audio is still playing after ending the call

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not releasing the same `MediaPlayer` instance as you created before.

A call to `MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.audio);` will create a new `MediaPlayer` instance each time. So in effect first time you receive broadcast `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` you start `MP_1` second time when you receive `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` you create a new `MP_2` and stop/release that instance. Instead keep MediaPlayer reference in your `BroadCast` class and only create one in `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`. Like so:

```
if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mp= MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.audio);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AcceptCall.class);
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                context.startActivity(intent1);

                    mp.setLooping(false);
                    mp.start();


                }


        }, 4000);

    }

    if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){

        try{
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Idle!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }
```

So later when you release it in `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` you release and stop the same one.

Also note that I've also replaced `mp.reset()...`.

Comment: @RaviPatil You might've registered the receiver twice, which will cause multiple calls to `onReceive()`. Also make sure `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` is already called once not twice.

Comment: **mp.stop()** showing error of cannot resolved symbol

Comment: thanks @abbas but i cant figure out that where is multiple calls to onReceive()